# Decidability of equality of expressions built using 1,+,-,*,/,^

Tags: decidability, algorithms, peano-arithmetic

Consider expressions built using number $1$, arithmetical operators $+, -, *, /$ and exponentiation ^ (in case of multiple values, [the principal value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_value) is assumed, the same way as it implemented in [Power](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Power.html) function in Mathematica).
Is it a [decidable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undecidable_problem) problem to check if such an expression is zero?
If so, could you please point me to an algorithm that can solve this problem?

Update: I found a reference to [Richardson's Theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RichardsonsTheorem.html), that establishes undecidablity of equality in a wider set of expressions, in particular, including the logarithm and absolute value functions.

Comment: I believe there is such an algorithm but it's quite complicated. 

Comment: Do you have any references?

Comment: If you are thinking on variables just taking values over real numbers it is known that the full first-order theory is decidable under Schanuel's conjecture. You can find more information in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarski%27s_exponential_function_problem

Comment: A related question: ["Is equivalence of functions built from nested exponentiations a decidable problem?"](http://mathoverflow.net/q/149360/33829)

Comment: Just to clarify: are you looking at expressions over the *real*, or the *complex* numbers? (I'm assuming it's the latter because of your remark about multiple-valuedness, but I just want to make sure.)

Comment: @NoahS Yes, the question is about complex numbers. We use the principal value of $a^b$, and let $a^b$ be undefined if $a=0$ and $b\le0$.

Comment: @StefanKohl In general, how do you evaluate the result of subtraction of two expression up to any desired precision? If the algorithm yields $0.000000...$ how do you know when to stop and if there is at least one non-zero digit? If you need the reciprocal of the difference, how do you know if it is defined at all?

Comment: @ZakhariaStanley: Sorry, I made a mistake in my tentative argumentation. -- I removed my comment. Though I think the question essentially is whether the value of an expression of length $n$ as described in the question is bounded above by a computable function in $n$ or not.

Comment: Similar question: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/145299/decidability-of-equality-of-elementary-expressions

Comment: An example:  Is $3^\sqrt{5}-2^\sqrt{2}=9$?  And what algorithm will solve problems of this kind?

Answer (score 8):

[The equational theory of $\langle {\bf N}, 0, 1, +, \times, \uparrow\rangle$ is decidable, but not finitely axiomatizable.](http://www.pps.univ-paris-diderot.fr/~dufour/zeronfa.pdf)

Comment: Thanks for the reference. But it looks like a different problem. The division operator $/$ takes it beyond integers and, together with $-$ and ^, beyond reals and algebraics.

Comment: That's right, I agree.

Comment: The link is broken

Comment: Permanent link https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-540-32275-7_17