# Is equivalence of functions built from nested exponentiations a decidable problem?

Tags: lo.logic, computability-theory, decidability, exponential-polynomials

Let $\mathcal{E}$ be the minimal set of symbolic expressions (without any predefined meaning) such that

- The symbol $x$ is in $\mathcal{E}$, and
- If expressions $P,Q\in\mathcal{E}$, then the superscript expression $(P)^{(Q)}\in \mathcal{E}$.

For every expression $S\in\mathcal{E}$, define the *interpretation* of $S$ as the function $\mathbb{R}^+\to\mathbb{R}^+$ given by $x\mapsto S$, where each occurrence of $x$ in $S$ is considered as the function parameter, and superscript expressions are considered as exponentiations. Note that we concern ourselves only with positive values of $x$.

We can make an observation that interpretations of two structurally distinct expressions can be the same function, e.g. the expressions 
$$\left((x)^{(x)}\right)^{\left((x)^{(x)}\right)},\ \left((x)^{\left((x)^{(x)}\right)}\right)^{(x)}$$
 both have the same function $x\mapsto x^{x^{x+1}}$ as their interpretation.

---

*Questions:*

- Is there an algorithm that for every pair of expressions from $\mathcal{E}$ can decide whether they have the same interpretation?
- If yes, can we give an explicit example of such algorithm?

Comment: It is clear that inequivalence of expressions is computably recognizable, since when two expressions are not equivalent, then they differ at a rational point in such a way that can be revealed by sufficiently accurate computation. So the equivalence problem is at worst co-c.e. The question is whether conversely there is some c.e. system that can prove all true instances of equivalence.

Comment: Related: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/140159/numbers-that-are-generic-w-r-t-exponentiation

Comment: Suppose we change the class slightly: x is in E'; if P_1, ..., P_n are in E', then x^(P_1 * ... * P_n) is in E'.  Every expression in E is computably reducible to one in E', and vice versa.  Without just rearranging products (perhaps we require multiplicands to be arranged by Gödel number), are there distinct expressions in E' that give rise to the same function?  If not, there's a straightforward algorithm for deciding equality of expressions in E.

Comment: @DanTuretsky, doesn't the OP provide an example of expressions that are distinct even in your E', which are equivalent? You seem to be hoping that the multiplicative simplification of that example is the only possible reason for equivalance; but is that right?

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins, neither of those are in my E', but they both reduce to x^( x * (x^x)).  And yes, that's precisely what I'm hoping.  It seems reasonable, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Does it become simpler if we consider functions $\mathbb{N}^+\to\mathbb{N}^+$ instead?

Comment: A related question: ["Decidability of equality of expressions built using 1,+,-,*,/,^"](http://mathoverflow.net/q/129563/33829)

Comment: Another related question: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/118972

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem is effectively decidable, and we will describe an algorithm. By way of preparation, we need to mention the o-minimality of the real exponential field, and Wilkie's solution to Tarski's High School Algebra problem.

The real exponential field $\mathbb{R}_{exp}$ is the field of real numbers  with an additional unary function $x\mapsto e^x$. Wilkie proved that $\mathbb{R}_{exp}$ is o-minimal, meaning that that every definable set of reals  is a finite union of intervals.

Note that the function $x^x$ is definable in $\mathbb{R}_{exp}$. Indeed, $y=x^x$ if and only if 
$$\exists u\,\,(x=e^u\wedge y=e^{ux}),$$
(using $x^x=e^{x\ln x}$). Since definable functions are closed under composition, all of the tower expressions in $\mathcal{E}$ are definable in $\mathbb{R}_{exp}$.

Now suppose two expressions $f,g\in\mathcal{E}$ define the same function on the natural numbers. Let $S$  be the set of positive real numbers $x$ for which $f(x)=g(x)$. Then $S$ is a definable subset of $R_{exp}$. Therefore $S$ is a finite union of intervals. Since $S$ contains every positive integer, it follows that $S$ contains some interval $(x_0,\infty)$.

But all of the functions defined by elements of $\mathcal{E}$ are analytic on $\mathbb{R}^+$. It follows immediately from 
 the principle of  real analytic continuation (see e.g. Corollary 1.2.5 of A Primer of Real Analytic Functions by Krantz and Parks)  that  $f$ and $g$ define the same function on $\mathbb{R}^+$.

So  we are reduced to solving the identity problem for $\mathcal{E}$ interpreted over the positive integers. 
This brings us to Tarski's High School Algebra Problem and Wilkie's solution. Tarski wrote down a set of axioms for the equational theory of the structure $(\mathbb{N},\,+,\,\times,\,e,\,1)$, where $e$ is binary exponentiation. These so-called High School Axioms are the (positive) semiring axioms together with the rules of exponentiation
\begin{align*}
&x^1=x,\,\,1^x=x\\
&(xy)^z=x^zy^z\\
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Following Exponent rule corrected
&x^{y+z}=x^yx^z\\
&(x^y)^z=x^{yz}.
\end{align*}
Tarski asked if the whole equational theory can be deduced from these. The answer is no. Wilkie found 'exotic' identities not deducible from the above, and he gave a computably enumerable set of identities from which the whole equational theory is indeed deducible.

Returning to identities for $\mathcal{E}$, we now have an algorithm. Given a possible identity, use Wilkie's axioms to look for it by listing all equations between elements of $\mathcal{E}$ that hold for all natural numbers. At the same time plug in integers $1,2,\ldots$ looking for a counterexample. One of these two processes will terminate after finitely many steps.

Wilkie's paper is available from CiteSeer [here.](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.15.9695)

There is a Wikipedia article on Tarski's High School problem [here.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarski%27s_high_school_algebra_problem)

It would be interesting to know if there is a nice analytic proof (avoiding Wilkie's theorem on the o-minimality of $\mathbb{R}_{exp}$) that the functions defined on $\mathbb{R}^+$ by the expressions in $\mathcal{E}$ are determined by their values on the positive integers.

Answer (score 6):

This is a justification of the algorithm suggested in Dan Turetsky's comment.

Every expression in $E$ reduces to an expression in $E'$ which is the minumum language such that $x\in E'$ and $x^{(p_1*\dots*p_n)}\in E'$ whenever $p_1,\dots,p_n\in E'$. Let us define a linear order on $E'$ as follows.

First, every expression in $E'$ has a level, which is the maximum number of nested exponentiations. More precisely, the level of $x$ is 0, and the level of $x^{(p_1*\dots*p_n)}$ is the maximum of the levels of $p_i$'s plus one. Let $E_n$ denote the set of expresions of level at most $n$.

We define our linear order on $E_n$ by induction. First of all, $x$ is the minimal element of our order. Let $f,g\in E_n$ and $f,g\ne x$. Then $f=x^{p_1*\dots*p_m}$ and $g=x^{q_1*\dots*q_k}$ where $p_i$'s and $q_j$'s are from $E_{n-1}$. Let us sort $p_i$'s and $q_j$'s in non-ascending order with respect to the (already defined) linear order on $E_{n-1}$. Then we say that $f>g$ iff the sequence $(p_i)$ is lexocographically bigger than $(q_j)$, i.e. $p_l>q_l$ where $l$ is the first index of mismatch (or $(q_j)$ is an initial subsegment of $(p_i)$). Clearly this definition is consistent with its previous stage, so we have a well-defined linear order on $E'$. This order is easy to compute.

I claim that, if $f>g$ in this linear order, then $f$ dominates $g$ at infinity, i.e. $f(x)>g(x)$ for all sufficiently large $x\in\mathbb R_+$. Moreover, $f$ dominates $g^a$ for any $a\in\mathbb N$. The latter claim is easy to prove by induction. Indeed, $x^x$ dominates $x^a$, and the induction step goes as follows. Let $f=x^{p_1*\dots*p_m}$ and $g=x^{q_1*\dots*q_k}$ and $f>g$. We need to prove that  $f$ dominates $g^a$, or, equivalently, that the product $p_1\dots p_m$ dominates $aq_1\dots q_k$. By removing common initial terms we may assume that $p_1>q_1$ in our order. (If all $q_j$'s cancel out completely, it remains to prove that $p_1$ dominates the constant $a$ and this is trivial.) Now by induction hypothesis, $p_1$ dominates $q_1^{k+1}$, which dominates $q_1^2q_2\dots q_k$, which dominates $aq_1\dots q_k$, q.e.d.

Comment: Yes. Right to the point!